# What is the sequence of Netlogo execution?

Tags: netlogo

Have I got this correct please?

If I write:

```
ask turtles
[go_forward
go_backward]
```

is it correct that a random turtle will move forward then move backward, and then a second random turtle will do the same, and so on? As opposed to:

```
ask turtles [go_forward]
ask turtles [go_backward]
```

which will get all turtles in a random order to move forward, and then all turtles in a (different) random order to move backward.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. There's a very similar example right at the end of the section on `ask` in the NetLogo Programming Guide: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#ask

See also Ask Ordering Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.