# Synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: netlogo

The following code: does it use synchronous or asynchronous updating (the set statements) (schedule of events).

```
globals [larger smaller]
turtles-own [num]

to test
  create-turtles 50
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set num random 100
  ]

  ask turtles
  [ let nearest-turtle min-one-of other turtles [ distance myself ]
    let closed-agent-num [num] of nearest-turtle
    ifelse [num] of nearest-turtle > num
      [ set larger nearest-turtle
        set smaller self ]
      [ set smaller nearest-turtle
        set larger self]
    ifelse random 100 < [num] of larger - [num] of smaller
      [ ask smaller [ set heading [heading] of larger] ]
      [ ask larger [ set heading [heading] of smaller] ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Yeah.  Inexcusable typo.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in NetLogo is synchronous. There is no concept of a "schedule of events". See [What is the sequence of Netlogo execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34872363/86485)

Comment: Ok, so the agents do everything in one go. I'll make different ask turtles statements

Comment: each turtle does everything in the [] after the ask, then the next turtle and so on. if you want all the turtles to, for example, calculate their next move before any of them move, simply do two ask statements - one for calculation and then one for moving

Comment: So to clarify your answer: what you mean is that the first random turtle looks at who is the nearest turtle and executes the second if else statement. Then the second random turtle, sees who is the nearest and does the second if else statement? MY question is: will the second turtle access the changed environment caused by the first turtle or not? Or does the second turtle still uses the state of the environment before the first turtle acted?

Comment: the second turtle access the environment CHANGED by the first turtle. see my other comment